# Docker compose mysql exited with code 0

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to add mysql to a docker compose file, but every time it gives me the error `some_name exited with code 0`. I tried diffent configurations and even took the following config from the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql/#-via-docker-stack-deploy-or-docker-compose):

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

In this case adminer works but mysql doesn't.

My config:

```
mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    container_name: ${MYSQL_HOST}
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "8989:3306"
```

Both my config and that from the docker docs keep giving me the same error. Although any other services are working fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How unfortunate. After hours I deleted my mysql image and after that everything worked fine.

Comment: some do `docker image prune -a -f` after each `docker-compose up`.